# Google website translator script interferes with the left value of jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

Google website translator script interferes with the left value of jquery dialog box.

When the screen is loaded, the dialog box is initially centered and then pushed right.
I do not know why this is happening.
Can I launch the dialog wherever I want?

This is the sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
   new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>

<body style="width:500px;margin:auto;">
<p>body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ </p>

<div class="popup0_dialog" title="NOTICE">
 <p>This dialog box will be pushed right.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  // catation dialog 옵션
  $(".popup0_dialog").dialog({
   dialogClass: "popup0_dialog_class",
   position: {my: "center top ", at: "center top+100", of: "body"},
  });
 });

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried `window` versus `body`?

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lakv527p/2/

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for reply. An error occurs when switching to 'window'. Google Translate does not seem to work in jsfiddle. I finally knew what makes the problem. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from other community told me the answer.
Google website translator made body to have position:relative.
By making new div which have the width value instead under the body element, I can solve this problem.

If you have any other good solutions, please let me know.

```
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;margin:auto;">
        <p>body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ body comment~ </p>

        <div class="popup0_dialog" title="NOTICE">
            <p>This dialog box will be pushed right.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```